# Extract data from URL with Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, parsing, url

I'm new to ruby and I'm trying to return a list of ASINs and corresponding prices using Ruby. I was able to get pretty close to what I need but would need help to answer 2 questions:

1. How can I get rid of the **[['** and **>\n"]]** around the ASIN (see result below)
2. Is there a simpler way to extract the ASIN from the URL than using this regex?

Thanks so much for your help!

Here is what I get in the Terminal from the current code:

```
[["B00EJDIG8M\n"]] - $7.00
[["B00KJ07SEM\n"]] - $26.99
[["B000FAR33M\n"]] - $119.00
[["B00LLMKPVK\n"]] - $22.99
[["B007NXPAQG\n"]] - $9.47
[["B004W5WAMU\n"]] - $22.43
[["B00LFUNGU0\n"]] - $17.99
[["B0052G14E8\n"]] - $54.99
[["B002MPLYEW\n"]] - $212.99
[["B00009W3G7\n"]] - $6.61
[["B000NCTOUM\n"]] - $3.04
[["B009SANIDO\n"]] - $12.29
[["B0052G51AQ\n"]] - $67.99
[["B003XEUEPQ\n"]] - $26.74
[["B00CYH9HRO\n"]] - $25.75
[["B00KV0SKQK\n"]] - $21.99
[["B009PCI2JU\n"]] - $56.66
[["B00LLM6ZFK\n"]] - $24.99
[["B004RQDY60\n"]] - $18.40
[["B000JLNBW4\n"]] - $49.14
```

Here is the code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'   
require 'open-uri'
PAGE_URL = "http://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Appliances/zgbs/appliances/ref=zg_bs_nav_0"

page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(PAGE_URL))
page.css(".zg_itemWrapper").each do |item|  
  price = item.at_css(".zg_price .price").text
  asin = item.at_css(".zg_title a")[:href].scan(/http:\/\/(?:www\.|)amazon\.com\/(?:gp\/product|[^\/]+\/dp|dp)\/([^\/]+)/)
  puts "#{asin} - #{price}"  
end
```

Comment: What you're seeing is a doubly nested array with a string in it. If they're showing up in your output it's probably because of how you scraped them from the results. For instance, `scan` returns arrays like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than cleaning up your Nokogiri search, the easiest thing to do at this point is just clean up your current *asin* values during interpolation. For example:

```
puts "#{asin.flatten.pop.chomp} - #{price}"
```

Comment: `asin.join.chomp` could do it as well.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding question 2., I realized I don't really need regex and found a way to get the same result with a much shorter line of code

replacing

```
asin = item.at_css(".zg_title a")[:href].scan(/http:\/\/(?:www\.|)amazon\.com\/(?:gp\/product|[^\/]+\/dp|dp)\/([^\/]+)/)
```

with

```
asin =  item.at_css(".zg_title a")[:href].split("/")[5].chomp
```